# Information set for ARMA Time series

Tags: time-series, probability, mathematical-statistics, arima

Given the following univariate ARMA(p,q) process $$ (X_{t})_{t\in Z  } $$

$$
X_{t}=\alpha_{0} + \alpha_{1}X_{t-1}+...+\alpha_{p}X_{t-p}+\theta_{1}\epsilon_{t-1}+...+\theta_{q}\epsilon_{t-q}+\epsilon_{t}
$$
$$ \epsilon_{t}\sim D(0,\sigma^2), $$ 
where $\epsilon_{t}$ is White Noise and $D$ denotes any distribution.

The information set at time $t-1$ often contains all values of $X_t$ from the infinite past up to time $t-1$, i.e. $$\Phi_{t-1}= \{X_{t-1},X_{t-2},...\}.$$

Conditional distributions and conditional moments of $X_t$  are then conditioned on exactly this information set. For example,

$$X_t|\Phi_{t-1}\sim D(\alpha_{0} + \alpha_{1}X_{t-1}+...+\alpha_{p}X_{t-p}+\theta_{1}\epsilon_{t-1}+...+\theta_{q}\epsilon_{t-q},\sigma^2)$$
$$\mathbb{E}[X_t|\Phi_{t-1}]=\alpha_{0} + \alpha_{1}X_{t-1}+...+\alpha_{p}X_{t-p}+\theta_{1}\epsilon_{t-1}+...+\theta_{q}\epsilon_{t-q}$$
$$V[X_t|\Phi_{t-1}]=\sigma^2.$$

For me it seems that the conditional distributions do not depend on the entire history of $X_t$, but only on the $p$ most recent realizations of $X_t$ and $q$ most recent realizations of $\epsilon_{t}$. If I know the most recent realizations, I can uniquely state the conditional distribution. But why do we assume the information set $\Phi_{t-1}$ to contain infinitely many past realizations?

Comment: Why do you worry? This concept of information set is most used theoretically, in certain proofs depending on results from probability theory. There such a non-decreasing sequence of subsigmaalgebras is called an *filtering*, and much used in martingale theory (I didn't encounter it otherwise). So it is to be able to use such results. So I see no reason to worry.